# How can I delete everything before/after a specific occurrence of a character?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

**Input**

`|1|2|3|4|5|`

**Output**

`|3|4|`

How can I delete everything before pipe number X `|` (3 in this example) and everything after pipe number Y (5 in this example)?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand what you mean here. I see 6 pipes. Why delete pipes 1-2 and 5? How can we know which ones to delete?

Comment: @terdon that's my question exactly is to call pipe by it's number, which mean's delete all before 3th pipe and all after 5th pipe in my example, got it?

Comment: with so many of your questions answered related to these tags, surely by now you'd be able to try something and show code/research effort? if you need learning resources, just hover over the tags and click info

Comment: @Sundeep thanks mate, I'm into this already, any resource for learning will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `awk`:

```
$ awk -F"|" -vOFS="|" '{print "|"$4,$5"|"}' file
|3|4|
```

Perl:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -lane 'print join "|", "",@F[3..4],""' file
|3|4|
```

Answer (score 0):

input file

example.txt

```
|1|2|3|4|5|
```

command:

---

```
awk '{print substr($1,5,5)}' example.txt
```

---

output

---

```
|3|4|
```

---